# Creating triangulated grid mesh using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mesh

So I have been creating mesh's using software called BlueKenue for hydraulic models, which is great. In the document I am currently writing I would like to include an image of the mesh however the mesh's I have constructed are very long in the x-axis and short in the y direction. Unfortunately BlueKenue will not allow you to have different scale ranges on your axis (or if it does I have not been able to find a way), i.e. if you have increments of 5 on one axis you will have likewise on the other. I have included an image of the mesh I currently have to illustrate my problem. If I can construct this mesh in matplotlib I can then ensure my image is suitably clear.

My question is can I reproduce this mesh in Matplotlib in a relatively simple way? (I am fairly new to python). The mesh is a regular grid which has been triangulated.

[image: Triangulated grid]

Edit:

Mesh dimensions 29.76 x 2

x intervals = 0.16m (186 points along the x axis)

y intervals = 0.20m (10 points along the y axis)

Thanks

Comment: yes, just plot each single segment in matplotlib, I don't see the problem. However this will take some time. Why don't you just postprocess with inkscape/illustrator the plot generated with BlueKenue, squeezing it horizontally?

Comment: @user3771983 you didn't describe the property of the mesh you would like to generate and the resolution of the posted image is not good enough to distinguish the `red mesh`!

Comment: Apologies i will edit the question with some more accurate dimensions.